# Neo4j - Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I think I need help on Neo4j (Graph database)

I have medium size data (~300 json objects) in JSON file (~250MB). I have to create graph database by using this file.

But I got this an exception:

> Exception in thread "qtp2007561282-66" Exception in thread
> "neo4j.TransactionTimeoutMonitor-29" Exception in thread
> "neo4j.FileIOHelper-12" Exception in thread "neo4j.IndexSampling-17"
> Exception in thread "neo4j.FileIOHelper-20" 2021-06-27
> 03:44:06.265+0000 WARN   Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
> Java heap space Exception in thread "neo4j.StorageMaintenance-28"
> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" Exception in thread
> "neo4j.FileIOHelper-4" Exception in thread "qtp2007561282-65"
> 2021-06-27 03:44:06.280+0000 WARN   Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Exception in thread
> "neo4j.FileIOHelper-18" 2021-06-27 03:44:06.293+0000 WARN   Java heap
> space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 2021-06-27
> 03:44:06.416+0000 ERROR Unexpected error detected in bolt session
> 'bolt-16'. Could not initialize class
> org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils

My Cipher SQL query is something like that:

```
with "file:///data.json" as url
call apoc.load.json(url)
yield value
merge (c:Company {register: value.info.register_number})
on create set c.name = value.info.company_name,
c.form = value.info.company_form,
c.register_date = value.info.register_date,
c.type = value.info.company_type,
c.number_of_owners = value.info.number_of_owner,
c.location = value.info.company_location
foreach (holder in value.stakeHolders | 
merge (p:Person {person_id : holder.firstname + "." + holder.lastname})
on create set p.firstname = holder.lastname,
p.lastname = holder.firstname,
p.country = holder.country
create (holder1:RegisterDate {date: holder.date})
merge (p)-[:has]->(holder1)-[:holder_of]->(c)
)
foreach (manager in value.ceo | 
merge (m:Person {person_id: manager.lastname + "." + manager.firstname})
on create set m.firstname = manager.firstname,
m.lastname = manager.lastname,
m.country = manager.country
create (manager1:RegisterDate {
position: manager.position,
date: manager.date
})
merge (m)-[:has]->(manager1)-[:has_position]->(c)
)
foreach (area in value.area |
merge (a:ActivityArea {code: area.code})
on create set a.title = area.title
create (area1:RegisterDate {
date: area.date
})
merge (c)-[:has]->(area1)-[:operation]->(a))
```

What should I do? please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Increase your jvm heap size in neo4j configuration file found in config folder then do a restart.

```
 file: <neo4j-home>/conf/neo4j.conf
```

Here is the documentation about it.
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/neo4j-conf/#neo4j-conf-JVM

Comment: I did it. But still error occurs do you have any an idea?